# "Online customers" didn't show any customer (empty)

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, database, customer

I have a production magento 1.7 website. After migrated from a old server to a new one, from unknown reason the "Online Customers" under "Customers" didn't show any Online customers when there are actually many customer visit the site. I tried to google this problem but found nothing. The only change, from the old server to the new server, is the DB server switched from mysql 5.5 to MariaDB 10. Anything i can do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe the config value is 0 instead to empty or something else. Goto System / Configuration / Customer / Online Customers Options -> Online Minutes Interval

Comment: Although closed I'd like to report we have the exact same issue. Online customer under Customers -> online customers is empty and has always been empty since a long time. We use Magento 1.9.0.1 and Online MInute Interval tested both with {empty} and 30 minutes. nada.

Comment: Check this: this may be the cause. That someone or something set this: http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/12/how-to-disable-magento-logging-to-the-database/